# Is rolling friction different from static friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction

In case of car movement, static friction is responsible for acceleration of car. Does the rolling friction act even when car is accelerating or it acts only when power supplied by the Engine is zero? Is that rolling friction is responsible for maintaining constant speeds of car even at low speeds; say 10kmph(in first gear)?